# Need help with regular expression when only one number changes in string

Tags: java, regex

How to check in Java with regular expression if some string matches with

```
Monday ptnumber Operating Mode
```

where number ( after pt ) has concrete value like 0,1,...99,.. - any integer?
Mondaypt    and Operating mode are hardcoded just number can change in string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will also extract the number.

```
String input ="Monday pt23 Operating Mode";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Monday pt([0-9]+) Operating Mode");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
boolean found = m.find();
if (found) {
    String number = m.group(1);
    System.out.println(number);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean matches = input.matches("Monday pt[0-9]+ Operating Mode");
```

Answer (score 1):

@Mark Peters & @Joachim Sauer gave good answer. But I'd like to add short comment.

use \d  instead of [0-9] and \s+ instead of space, i.e. `"Monday\\s+\\d+\\s+Operating Mode"`. Now the regex is less strict: it allows number of spaces. For me \d is more readable than [0-9]

1. method `matches` automatically adds ^ in the beginning and $ in the end of regex. Use `Matchermfind()` instead.
2. Compilation of pattern is very CPU intensive process. It is good practice to use Pattern.compile() for all static patterns during the application initialization and then use the ready pattern. String.mantches() actually creates pattern and then runs it.

`private static Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Monday\\s+\\d+\\s+Operating Mode");`

`// now use it:`

`p.matcher(str).find();`

Answer (score 0):

```
String input = "Monday 24 Operating Mode";
if ( input.matches ( "Monday [0-9]+ Operating Mode" ) ) {
    //...it matches...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `input.matches("Monday \\d{0,2} Operating Mode");`

Answer (score 0):

```
input.matches("Monday pt(\\d+) Operating Mode");
```